# How to create a Locality for a Hospital from belongs to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, belongs-to

### Model:

**Hospital**

```
belongs_to :locality
```

**Locality**

```
has_many :hospitals
```

How to create a new Locality for a Hospital, kindly help

```
h = Hospital.new
l = h.locality.new
l.name = "america"
l.save
```

Comment: what did you try? what is the error? did you try h.save  ?

Comment: it's weird that you're trying to create a locality from a hospital. usually you build from locality first then build a hospital after.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
l = h.locality.new
```

You should do:

```
l = h.build_locality
```

On Rails Guides you can read the [explanation of `build_locality`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs_to-build_association).